# wordpress website not opening just download archives

Tags: wordpress

I wanted to see what this reason could be. When entering my site: https://boonmodels.com/
It doesn't log in, it just downloads some strange files.
I have not touched anything, will it be a problem of a virus or something similar?
the site is made in wordpress.
I hope someone can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your site is suddenly downloading files instead of visiting the page, do not open them.

Are you on shared hosting? Either way, contact your hosting provider immediately. Hopefully they have a backup to a time before it was doing this and can restore. They might also be able to confirm what the contents of the files would be without you endangering your own computer.

I used to run into this problem with shared hosting on GoDaddy. I now no longer recommend Wordpress unless you are on your own Virtual Private Server or with a managed hosting service like WPEngine.

Comment: The site is on a dedicated server, I already speak to the administrator of it to see what happens, I appreciate your answer!

Comment: @matigcba I see that your site is working fine now without any issue.